# Bootstrap datepicker large spaces

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap datepicker from online resources to my existing website. But when I tried to use my existing `style.css` file I got below huge date spaces to the calendar. It was obvious that my current css file affecting the datepicker, how can I bypass the attributes from my `style.css` about the datepicker to remove this or what specific attributes to change?

So far this is the close enough I tried, but it's just for the table and the spaces still the same.

```html
<style type = "text/css">
.datepicker,
.table-condensed {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
</style>
```

[image]

Here's the online resource datepicker script.

```html
<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<div class="bootstrap-iso">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <!-- Form code begins -->
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </form>
     <!-- Form code ends --> 

    </div>
  </div>    
 </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant style.css rules that is causing this

Comment: just remove ```.datepicker,``` from your style.

Comment: If you  send relevant style.css only we have try to fix , otherwise it challenge one.